# buscar dato en ventana modal

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

estoy teniendo el siguiente problema con jquery y ajax: Tengo una vista con un formulario que es alimentado en algunos campos mediante ajax y jquery, esto esta funcionando bien, ademas tengo una ventana modal que al abrir me trae datos de la bd mediante el id que le paso a este ventana desde mi vista principal, me funciona bien igual, pero ahora debo en esta ventana modal hacer una "Busqueda en vivo", es decir, ingresar un valor en un input y que me muestre si el dato ingresado esta en la bd o no, y es aca donde viene mi problema, dado que al intentar consultar, se cierra el modal y no se si se muestra algun dato...

EDIT: Este es el codigo del modal:

```
    <!--MODAL CAGRA DE ARCHIVO DE SERIES-->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modal-seriado" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Asignación de Series a Material</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="series">Ingresar Serie a Asignar(Podria generar un array almacenando todas las id que se pistoleen y ese array gurdarlo)</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search" name="search" >
                     <input type="text" id="resultado" name="resultado">
                </div>

          {{--   <div class="form-group">
                <label for="series">Seleccione Serie(s) Disponible(s)</label>
                <input type="text" >
                <select name="series[]" id="series" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple">
                 </select>
            </div> --}}
            <input type="submit" value="Aceptar">
        </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  @section('js-modal')
 <script>

     //console.log("hola desde le modal");
     $(document).ready(function(){

       $('#search').on('keyup', function(){
           $value = $(this).val();
            buscarSerie(mac);
       })

       function buscarSerie(mac){
            var mac = $('#search').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"{{ url('logistica/series/search') }}"+`/${mac}`,
                data:{
                    'search_query' : mac
                },
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    $('#resultado').html(data);
                }
            });
       }

    });

 </script>
@stop
```

En el controlador tengo esta funcion:

```
 public function buscarSerieMac($mac){
        //$mac = $request->get('buscador'); //indicamos que el valor a buscar viene desde ese inout del form
        //$serie = DetSerializacion::where('mac','like',"%$mac%");
        $data = DetSerializacion::find($mac);
        return view('persona.logistica.asignacion.modalSeries', compact('data'));
    }
```

y en el modelo, esta funcion:

```
 public static function seriesDisponiblesAsignacion($search_keyword) {
        $users = DB::table('det_serializacions');

        if ($search_keyword && !empty($search_keyword)) {
           $users->where(function($q) use ($search_keyword){
                $q->where('det_serializacions.mac', 'like', "%{search_keyword}%") //'%' .$valor. '%'
                ->orWhere('det_serializacions.serie', 'like',  "%{search_keyword}%");
            });
        }

        return $users;

    }
```

Que podria hacer en este caso?, alguna recomendacion? ya que al ingresar un valor y apretar enter, se cierra el modal y no se  muestra ninguna informacion

Saludos a todos

Comment: Muestra qué código tienes introducido. Si no vemos nada, es más difícil poder ayudarte

Comment: @Zander hola estimado, actualize el codigo...